# Error while append datedata to data object

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

I want to append some date data to data object but getting following error:

> TypeError: data is not iterable

```js
  const onSubmit = async data => {
    const datedata = {
      CheckinDate: startDate,
      CheckoutDate: endDate
    };
    console.log(...data, ...datedata);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
  const onSubmit = async data => {
    data.CheckinDate = startDate;
    data.CheckoutDate = endDate;
    console.log(data);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You use spread operator (`...data, ...datedata`); Non of `data` and `datedata` aren't iterable. Iterable objects are a generalization of arrays. That’s a concept that allows us to make any object useable in a `for..of` loop.

Of course, Arrays are iterable. But there are many other built-in objects, that are iterable as well. For instance, strings are also iterable.

If an object isn’t technically an array but represents a collection (list, set) of something, then `for..of` is a great syntax to loop over it, so let’s see how to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

as you wish, you can append some date data to data object

```js
 const datedata = {
      CheckinDate: startDate,
      CheckoutDate: endDate,
      ...data
    };
```

or

```js
const mixData = {
  ...data,
  ...datedata,
}
```